# ¿Como puedo comparar un dato que recibo de Arduino a javascript para cambiar el color de un div?

Tags: javascript, css, nodejs, arduino, style

Estoy recibiendo datos de Arduino por medio de Node.js utilizando el serialport, yo puedo ver esos datos por la terminal pero necesito comparar esos datos mediante un `if` para poder cambiar el color de una casilla div, el siguiente código es que estoy usando para recibir los datos y mostrarlos por el terminal me falta hacer la comparación pero aun no se como hacerlo.

```
/*CONEXIÓN POR MEDIO DEL PUERTO SERIAL ARDUINO A JavaScript MEDIANTE Nodejs*/
const SerialPort = require("serialport");
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
const parser = new Readline();
/*LEER EL PUERTO SERIAL*/
const mySerial = new SerialPort("COM4", {
  baudRate: 9600,
});
/*INDICA QUE SE ESTA COMUNICANDO CON LOS DATOS DEL PUERTO*/
mySerial.on("open", function () {
  console.log("puerto abierto");
});
/*MUESTRA LOS DATOS POR LA TERMINAL*/
mySerial.on("data", function (data) {
  console.log(data.toString()); /*LOS DATOS RECIBIDOS SE MUESTRAN POR LA TERMINAL*/
});
/*SI GENERA ALGUN ERROR LO NOTIFICA */
mySerial.on("err", function (err) {
    console.log(err.message());
})
```

Que me recomiendan hacer para la comparación y se pueda cambiar el color.

Comment: ¿Puedes usar un simple `if`? ¿Qué tipo de datos vas a recibir?

Comment: números enteros estoy recibiendo datos de un ultrasonido para medir distancia, y con esos dato dependiendo de la distancia debo cambiar el color de una casilla

Comment: ¿Le quieres hacer comparación a que cosa?